# Comparing rotated images

Tags: image-processing, ocr

I'm looking for a way to compare images that are almost identical (95%+ similarity) but that could be rotated around a central axis.

I'm new to the whole computer graphics/vision field, and not really sure if there is a ready built tool or system for it, or even if this is the right stack exchange to ask on.

Currently, I'm investigating using C# to generate a bitmap histogram, then running it through Panda for analysis and to ideally group the images based on the similarity of histograms, though I've heard something like OpenCv + tesseract may be a viable alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare image similarity using feature point extraction and matching using rotation and scale invariant algorithms.

Already rotation invariant feature matching algorithms are available in OpenCV -  [SIFT](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/da/df5/tutorial_py_sift_intro.html)
,SURF but these are patented so you have to pay if you want to use them commercially.

Fortunately an efficient alternative to SIFT or SURF is available namely [ORB](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d1/d89/tutorial_py_orb.html) (Oriented FAST and Rotated BRIEF)

These algorithms work fine in most of the images except a few like document images.

PS: As mentioned in the question (OpenCV + tesseract) alternatively can be used for document images by extracting the text contents in the image using [Tesseract](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract) library(Opensource OCR engine)

Comment: Thanks for this. I started using a mix of ORB and SURF which seems to allow a solution.

Answer (score 3):

You need to compute the affine transformation matrix between your two images in order the get the information regarding scaling, translation and **rotation**.

How this matrix looks and how can you get the rotation difference?

[From this answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23875280/5165833)

[image]

I have used the following **Java** code (using OpenCV 3.2) which computes the **scaling**, **translation** and **rotation** difference between two Mat images. I hope you will find it useful.

```
static void calculateDifferences(Mat img1, Mat img2){

        // Initialization
        FeatureDetector detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.ORB);
        DescriptorExtractor descriptor = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.ORB);
        DescriptorMatcher matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING);

        // First image objects
        Mat img1_descriptors = new Mat();
        MatOfKeyPoint img1_keypoints_mat = new MatOfKeyPoint();

        // Detect KeyPoints for first image
        detector.detect(img1, img1_keypoints_mat);
        descriptor.compute(img1, img1_keypoints_mat, img1_descriptors);

        // Second image objects
        Mat img2_descriptors = new Mat();
        MatOfKeyPoint img2_keypoints_mat = new MatOfKeyPoint();

        // Detect KeyPoints for second image
        detector.detect(img2, img2_keypoints_mat);
        descriptor.compute(img2, img2_keypoints_mat, img2_descriptors);

        // Match KeyPoints
        MatOfDMatch matOfDMatch = new MatOfDMatch();
        matcher.match(img1_descriptors, img2_descriptors, matOfDMatch);

        // Filtering the matches
        List<DMatch> dMatchList = matOfDMatch.toList();
        Double max_dist = 0.0;
        Double min_dist = 100.0;

        for(int i = 0; i < img1_descriptors.rows(); i++){
            Double dist = (double) dMatchList.get(i).distance;
            if(dist < min_dist) min_dist = dist;
            if(dist > max_dist) max_dist = dist;
        }
        LinkedList<DMatch> good_matches = new LinkedList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < img1_descriptors.rows(); i++){
            if(dMatchList.get(i).distance < 3*min_dist){
                good_matches.addLast(dMatchList.get(i));
            }
        }

        // Converting to MatOfPoint2f format
        LinkedList<Point> img1_points_list = new LinkedList<>();
        LinkedList<Point> img2_points_list = new LinkedList<>();

        List<KeyPoint> img1_keyPoints_list = img1_keypoints_mat.toList();
        List<KeyPoint> img2_keyPoints_list = img2_keypoints_mat.toList();

        int limit = good_matches.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < limit; i++){
            img1_points_list.addLast(img1_keyPoints_list.get(good_matches.get(i).queryIdx).pt);
            img2_points_list.addLast(img2_keyPoints_list.get(good_matches.get(i).trainIdx).pt);
        }

        MatOfPoint2f img1_point2f_mat = new MatOfPoint2f();
        img1_point2f_mat.fromList(img1_points_list);

        MatOfPoint2f img2_point2f_mat = new MatOfPoint2f();
        img2_point2f_mat.fromList(img2_points_list);

        // Computing the affine transform matrix
        Mat result = Video.estimateRigidTransform(img1_point2f_mat, img2_point2f_mat, true);
        printMat(result); // Printing the optimal affine transformation 2x3 array

        // The following variables correspond to the estimateRigidTransform result as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29511091/5165833
        double a = result.get(0,0)[0];
        double b = result.get(0,1)[0];
        double d = result.get(1,1)[0];
        double c = result.get(1,0)[0];
        double tx = result.get(0,2)[0];
        double ty = result.get(1,2)[0];

        // Solving for scale,translation and rotation as shown in the link above
        double scale_x = Math.signum(a) * Math.sqrt( (a*a) + (b*b) ); // Axis x scale difference
        double scale_y = Math.signum(d) * Math.sqrt( (c*c) + (d*d) ); // Axis y scale difference
        double translation = ty; // The translation difference
        double rotation_angle = Math.atan2(c,d); // Rotation difference

        // Printing results
        println("Scale_x diff: " + scale_x);
        println("Scale_y diff: " + scale_y);
        println("Translation diff: " + translation);
        println("Rotation diff: " + rotation_angle);
    }

    static void printMat(Mat m)
    {
        for (int x=0; x < m.height(); x++) {
            for (int y=0; y < m.width(); y++) {
                System.out.printf("%f",m.get(x,y)[0]);
                System.out.printf("%s"," ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```